# Can I keep @Around advice from interception exceptions in methods?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I want to use an advice in a java spring project to set some contexts before and after certain methods for database transactions, but if there's an exception I don't want the around advice to intercept this exception. However, I still need the finally/after part of the advice to execute to do some final things.

Should I switch to just using the @Before and @After advice, or is there a possible workaround with the @Around advice?

Comment: And why would it intercept the exception? I don't really understand the problem. You do something before, call proceed, and in the finally part you cleanup (or whatever you do). You don't need to do anything with the exception.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, depending on your needs, either ignore the exception or log and re-throw it, whatever. Here are two possible variants to give you an idea:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class ErrorIgnoringAspect {
  @Around("execution(* org.acme..*(..))")
  public Object advice1(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(">> " + joinPoint);
    try {
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    finally {
      System.out.println("<< " + joinPoint);
    }
  }

  @Around("execution(* org.acme..*(..))")
  public Object advice2(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(">> " + joinPoint);
    try {
      Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
      System.out.println("<< " + joinPoint + " -> result = " + result);
      return result;
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
      System.out.println("<< " + joinPoint + " -> error = " + t);
      throw t;
    }
  }
}
```

If you just want to log the result or exception, and there is no need for exception handling, method parameter or result modification, of course you can also use a combination of `@Before`, `@AfterThrowing` (log exception) and `@AfterReturning` (log result), doing away with the need to use try-catch-finally or to proceed to the joinpoint.